# how to merge two rows of a single column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df,

```
Name |class |section
-------------------
Sri  |  A   |  B
----------------
Sri  |  B   |  C
```

My expected output is

```
Name |class |section
-------------------
     |  A   |  B
Sri  --------------
     |  B   |  C
```

I searched `pandas doc` but could not find, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible in pandas. What is reason for it?

Comment: for a good visualization of my output data